# Define class attribute according to object name

Tags: python, object, attributes

I'd like that an attribute is defined automatically as soon as an object is assigned to its class:

```
class someClass:
   
   def __init__(self, abbreviation):
       the first three letters of the object name = abbreviation

hello = someClass()
print(hello.abbreviation)
# expected output

hel
```

I'm sure this question has ben asked (so please feel free to redirect me) but I'm still quite new to this so not sure what to search for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why ? That is not really a good idea. You shouldn't store information in a variable name, why not passing it as parameter ? `someClass("hel")` ?

Comment: I don't see how this is storing information in a variable name. It is inheriting the name from the variable and storing it inside the attribute. Furthermore, I need to be able to manipulate the attribute in different ways e.g. upper() or add an extra int on the end in a systematic way.

Comment: As the information comes from the variable name, that is storing temporarly information in the variable name, that isn't a good practice.  Why not passing `someClass("hel")` ? then in the init you can do `self.abbreviation = abbreviation.upper()+"9"` without problem

Comment: Oh you can call methods when defining! Well, that solves my problem entirely. Thank you! :D

Comment: Probably worth reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1):

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, attr):
         self.attr = attr[:3]

myObject = MyClass("hello")
print(myObject.attr) # hel
```